# Import error when using a python script that do not occur in ipython

Tags: ipython

All my install for python were working pretty well since soon. Now, I have a weird issue that generates import errors for some of my Python scripts and when using Ipython those import performs as expected.

This issue does not depend on the working dir (tested this several times with the same result). And I didn't change anything in my .bashrc regarding PYTHONPATHs. 
So this might be a noob question, but is there an option in Ipython to display everything Ipython is doing when I run a command, so that I can track which is the package Ipython succesfully imported?

The packages I have trouble with are actually `yaml`, `matplotlib cloud Image`. Is it possible that an update from 2.6 to 2.7 is responsible for that? (I work on OSX Lion and most of the packages are installed via `macports` and updated using the `upgrade outdated` command).

As I think I can probably fix this myself with the command I asked for, don't bother seeking further for package compatibility or anything if you got the Ipython command that might suits me.

Comment: Hello again a total reinstallation of the py-27 packages via macports   following the whole process described here http://astrofrog.github.io/macports-python/ fixed the problem. Of course for the cloud package as no port exists the definition of the package directory to look for in the PYTHONPATH is still necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference of imports between python and ipython resulted from a cross defined python reference library (when installing most of the python libraries with macports and some without any known ports with other package managers).
Reinstalling the whole python libraries using the process described in http://astrofrog.github.io/macports-python/
corrects the issue and it is preferable to install manually the libraries that don't have any known ports (for instance with a setup build/install process).